# Unbind F1 'Help' keyboard shortcut in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can you unbind the <kbd>F1</kbd> keyboard shortcut in Eclipse?  I have unbound it using the Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys, but it appears to have no effect (<kbd>F1</kbd> still brings up the help pane, regardless of the binding in the Keys Preference).

Is <kbd>F1</kbd>/Help treated as a special case shortcut in Windows?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Nope.  I should probably file a bug.

Comment: F1 seem to have a different way of binding. Even inside configuring bindings if you try to enter F1 key inside text box for Binding ,the help menu gets popped up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) the <kbd>F1</kbd> is a system-wide shortcut, so you won't be able to remap it inside your application.

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't matter that <kbd>F1</kbd> generates a help event on Windows. As explained [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26772), SWT generates both a help event and a key event when <kbd>F1</kbd> is pressed. You can map things to <kbd>F1</kbd> and it will work, but it will still also open help.

To fix this, delete the JAR file in the plugins directory that starts with "org.eclipse.help.base". Help will no longer open!

Edit: in fact, I use this to smoke Eclipse junk:

```
rm -rf readme
rm -rf *.html

rm -rf features/org.eclipse.aether*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.cvs*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.egit*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.gef*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.help.ui*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.jgit*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.m2e*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.mylyn*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.team.cvs*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.wb*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.wst*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.xsd*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.epp.mpc*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.buildship*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.oomph*
rm -rf features/org.eclipse.recommenders*

rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.aether*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.cvs*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.egit*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.gef*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.jgit*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.m2e*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.wb*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.wst*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.xsd*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.epp.mpc*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.buildship*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.oomph*
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.recommenders*
```

Comment: That's so awesome!  I had taken to removing the F1 key from my keyboards, but deleting a jar file is much more elegant. :)  How did you figure that out?

Comment: I like having a nice clean Eclipse so I smoke all the JARs I can. :)

Comment: I would rather recommend to remove the "org.eclipse.help.ui" plugin because other plugins may depend of the "org.eclipse.help.base" and will therefore stop working.

Comment: @user9999999 I updated my answer to show everything I delete from Eclipse. I'm able to map F1 to my own shortcut without help opening in Neon.3 (4.6.3).

Comment: @user9999999 I delete from the Eclipse installation directory, which is where I unzipped "Eclipse for Java developers". I have F1 mapped to `Open Declaration` and it works, no help window.

Comment: @NateS I searched my Windows system and only found the files under .p2\pool, no such files in the eclipse install directory. I used the (64 bit) windows Eclipse installer. After a restart, F1 started working for the mapping I wanted, so your instructions are valid; sorry for the confusion! I just deleted the C:\Users\user9999999\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.help.ui*.jar files, for reference.

Comment: Yeah, for users that installed any Eclipse via the installer, a .p2 directory is created with shared settings and plugins between multiple Eclipse installations. Mine is under my home directory (C:/Users/Name/.p2) for Windows.

Comment: It is sufficient to just delete the plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui jar, there is no need to delete all the other jars as well (why would you delete egit, xsd, etc!). You should edit your answer to only delete the things related to the question, i.e. the help jar.

Comment: @jmiserez The answer is clear on what JAR to delete. There's nothing wrong with providing more information. I delete the other junk because I don't need it. You delete what you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you installed eclipse in the default location, go to:

```
C:\Users\[your username]\.p2\pool\plugins
```

and search for:

```
org.eclipse.help.base
```

then, **after closing eclipse**, add `.jbak` to the end of the file you found. This should fix the problem. If for whatever reason you need it back, just remove the `.jbak` from the file name and restart eclipse.

*Note: you will need to agree to windows warning and close eclipse **before** renaming the file.*

Answer (score -1):

Edit: below commands ruin your code completion if you used the OOMPH installer. I didn’t restore all plugins one by one, restart Eclipse to see if it works again, but just restored all OOMPH and recommenders features and plugins. For that I downloaded the Eclipse archive (in my case JEE) and just copied the features and plugins from the extracted archive to my .p2\pool\feature respectively \plugins.

To modify [@NateS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187883/nates)’s answer for PowerShell so you can just copy it. If you installed Eclipse via installer go to your .p2 directory (most likely C:\Users\Name.p2\pool and run the commands from there.

```
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.aether*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.gef*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.help.ui*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.jgit*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.m2e*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.mylyn*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.team.cvs*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.wb*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.wst*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.xsd*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.epp.mpc*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.buildship*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.oomph*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse features/org.eclipse.recommenders*

Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.aether*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.gef*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.jgit*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.m2e*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.wb*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.wst*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.xsd*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.epp.mpc*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.buildship*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.oomph*
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse plugins/org.eclipse.recommenders*
```

I actually like JGit and use it so I removed that line for the feature/ and plugins/. You could also comment them out by adding a `%` in front of the line.

Go to the directory where your eclipse.exe is (either way you choose the path yourself when you extracted the archive or when you installed it. Mine is under C:\eclipse\jee-oxygen\eclipse) and run these two commands.

```
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse readme
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse *.html
```